# Use .on on the complicated script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Tooltip only Text
$('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
        // Hover out code
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});

    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#app').append('<span title="add" class="masterTooltip">add</span> <br />');
    })

});
```

[LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/K77hg/)

Tooltip working if I click on button#add. I try change at the beginning:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.masterTooltip', function(){
```

and:

```
}).on('mousemove', function(e) {
```

but this not working. How can i make it in this script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nearly had it right, here's the working code:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.masterTooltip', function (e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
            .text(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }
}).on('mousemove', '.masterTooltip', function (e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20, //Get X coordinates
        mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('.tooltip')
        .css({
        top: mousey,
        left: mousex
    })
});
```

`.hover()` is just shorthand for both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

This code attaches one event handler for both those events then checks to see whether the event being triggered is `mouseenter`. If it is then the hover over code is run otherwise it must be a `mouseleave` event and so the hover out code is run.

Here's of demo in action: http://jsfiddle.net/K77hg/3/